# Ordering SQL results based on distance formula

Tags: php, sql, distance, formula

Not sure the topic appropriately describes what I'm attempting but here is the situation. I have a database of x, y coordinates and locations associated with them. I'd like to have users submit form data with an x and y coordinate and return the results in order of proximity sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2). I'm not really sure how to go about applying the distance formula to the results set to display. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really not that hard. Just put the proximity calculation into the order by clause. Your SQL will need to be dynamic so you can substitute in the x and y input values. I went ahead and selected the proximity calculation also, so that you can see the value used in the sorting.

select location, sqrt((x-{x input value})^2 + (y-{y input value})^2) as proximity
from locations
order by sqrt((x-{x input value})^2 + (y-{y input value})^2)

Answer (score 0):

The square root function is monotonically increasing, so if sqrt(a) is larger than sqrt(b), then a is larger than b. So if SQRT isn't available in your SQL dialect, you can just skip it:

```
ORDER BY (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)
```

Add that to the end of your SQL query.